# Angular 11 SSR is compiled,but having issue with prod build and serve no content showed up in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

```
{
   "$schema":"./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "version":1,
   "newProjectRoot":"projects",
   "projects":{
      "new-asasa":{
         "projectType":"application",
         "schematics":{
            
         },
         "root":"",
         "sourceRoot":"src",
         "prefix":"app",
         "architect":{
            "build":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
               "options":{
                  "outputPath":"dist/new-asasa/browser",
                  "index":"src/index.html",
                  "main":"src/main.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.app.json",
                  "aot":true,
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "src/styles.scss",
                     "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
                     "node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[
                     "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js",
                     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                  ],
                  "allowedCommonJsDependencies":[
                     "rxjs-compat",
                     "lodash"
                  ]
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "fileReplacements":[
                        {
                           "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
                           "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                     ],
                     "optimization":true,
                     "outputHashing":"all",
                     "sourceMap":false,
                     "namedChunks":false,
                     "extractLicenses":true,
                     "vendorChunk":false,
                     "buildOptimizer":true,
                     "budgets":[
                        {
                           "type":"initial",
                           "maximumWarning":"4mb",
                           "maximumError":"7mb"
                        },
                        {
                           "type":"anyComponentStyle",
                           "maximumWarning":"20kb",
                           "maximumError":"20kb"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "serve":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build:production"
                  }
               }
            },
            "extract-i18n":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build"
               }
            },
            "test":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
               "options":{
                  "main":"src/test.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.spec.json",
                  "karmaConfig":"karma.conf.js",
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "src/styles.scss"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[
                     "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "lint":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
               "options":{
                  "tsConfig":[
                     "tsconfig.app.json",
                     "tsconfig.spec.json",
                     "e2e/tsconfig.json",
                     "tsconfig.server.json"
                  ],
                  "exclude":[
                     "**/node_modules/**"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "e2e":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
               "options":{
                  "protractorConfig":"e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                  "devServerTarget":"new-asasa:serve"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "devServerTarget":"new-asasa:serve:production"
                  }
               }
            },
            "server":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
               "options":{
                  "outputPath":"dist/new-asasa/server",
                  "main":"server.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.server.json"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "outputHashing":"media",
                     "fileReplacements":[
                        {
                           "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
                           "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                     ],
                     "sourceMap":false,
                     "optimization":true
                  }
               }
            },
            "serve-ssr":{
               "builder":"@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build",
                  "serverTarget":"new-asasa:server"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build:production",
                     "serverTarget":"new-asasa:server:production"
                  }
               }
            },
            "prerender":{
               "builder":"@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"new-asasa:build:production",
                  "serverTarget":"new-asasa:server:production",
                  "routes":[
                     "/"
                  ]
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "defaultProject":"new-asasa",
   "cli":{
      "analytics":false
   }
}
```

`npm run dev:ssr` works fine and also show ssr content loaded in browser.
but when i run  `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` for production build ssr didn't work.

```
   "dev:ssr": "ng run new-asasa:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/new-asasa/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run new-asasa:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run new-asasa:prerender"    "dev:ssr": "ng run new-asasa:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/new-asasa/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run new-asasa:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run new-asasa:prerender"`
```

Comment: what is the error you see in build and/or runtime?

Comment: @Raz Ronen i didn't get any error it just compiled succesfully.

Comment: Any issue pop up in console in the browser?

Comment: @Raz Ronen no bro totaly clean console in browser no warning no error :|

Comment: what do you see in the network request? Is your .html been fetched? Are any javascript fetched later?

Comment: @Raz Ronen  .html is fetched but with out ssr content. And also all js files are fetched in network request

Comment: We need more details, can you add angular.json and your html?

Comment: @Raz Ronen ok i can share my angular.json file and which html file you want. Because i have many modules all have there own html files.

Comment: The last one that gets downloaded in the network tab please

Comment: Check your index.html inside build folder, If it's blank you will not see your app

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic behind your `serve:ssr` task, seems like you haven't understood the fundamentals of Angular Universal and how it's setup.

The compiled SSR code available at `node dist/new-asasa/server/main.js` is just application code. If you try to run it directly using Node, it will not do anything. This compiled file is to be used as the basis for your *server's view engine*. Whenever someone calls your server, you have to use this code to render HTML pages on the server and then send them back. This is something that needs to be set up, it doesn't come out of the box because Angular does not know which server you'll be using in advance.

The `serve-ssr` task looks like a convenience utility added quite recently which might have confused you into thinking that things were simpler than they actually are.

Anyhow, there's way too much to explain here, please follow the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/universal).